# How to store SQL columns in array C# winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to store my selected values from database in arrays so I can do computations on the values. I wrote the following code:

```
string command = @"select  
                      I.Dist, I.ID, D.ID, D.Temp,
                      CAST(D.Hmd as float) Hmd,
                      CAST(D.ActEvp as float) ActEvp 
                   from 
                      IFiles I 
                   inner join 
                      (select 
                          DFiles.ID, DFiles.Temp, DFiles.Hmd, DFiles.ActEvp 
                       from 
                          DFiles 
                       where 
                          FileName = '1') D on I.ID = CAST( D.ID as int) 
                   where 
                       FileName = 's1' 
                   order by 
                       CAST(I.Dist as float)";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MyDB;Initial Catalog=Graphic;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

con.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(ds, "DFiles");

List<float> Hmd = new List<float>();

foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["DFiles"].Rows)
{
    Hmd.Add(float.Parse(row["Hmd"].ToString()));
}
```

However I don't think it will be efficient if I do this for every single column. Is there a better way?

Comment: do you want to get the columns of a table?

Comment: Yes, leave them in your table.

Comment: Please, what is `ET`?

Comment: There are several ways: **(1)** use a Micro-ORM like Dapper to keep the "raw" SQL statement, but turn the results automagically into a `List<SomeClass>` - then Dapper does much of the mapping of relational data to your .NET class for you; or **(2)** - use a `SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()`, loop over all rows read by the data reader use `while (rdr.Read()) { ... }` and inside the while loop create objects and fill their properties with the values read from the database (that's basically what Dapper does for you - if you insist, you can code it all yourself)

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I want to get the selected values, which will be the columns of the select statement.

Comment: @Steve: do you mean to just fill the data table ?

Comment: Why do you convert row["Hmd"] to string then parse it to float!?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do with the data retrieved. You talk about calculations and efficiency but then, you are trying to transfer that data already in memory to another memory structure (list or arrays). The datatable is already a kind of glorified array. So it depends on what you need to do with that data.

Comment: @Tarik The data is varchar in database. and I want to normalize the data which is basically subtract from minimum and divide by range. then drawing a graph from the data

Comment: But you have this statement in your sql : CAST(D.Hmd as float) Hmd

Comment: @Tarik Yes but when I create a list of float, then the list takes float type but the row is still an object.

Comment: In that case, just cast it to a float.

Comment: IMHO there is no point in creating a data structure by hand while you can use the designer to create a typed dataset/datatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First step**: define your "DTO" (data transfer object) to hold the values you read from the database:

```
public class DTO
{
    public string Dist { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int DID { get; set; }
    public string Temp { get; set; }
    public decimal Hmd { get; set; }
    public decimal ActEvp { get; set; }
}
```

(*I had to guess what datatype those values might be - adapt as needed*)

**Second step**: install "Dapper Dot Net" into your Visual Studio solution (easiest way is via NuGet - [or you can get it from here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) on Github)

**Third step**: use Dapper to make your database access **much** simpler:

```
string command = "......";  // your SQL query, as before

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MyDB;Initial Catalog=Graphic;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    IEnumerable<DTO> results = con.Query<DTO>(command);
    con.Close();
}
```

That's **all there is!** Now you have a nice proper .NET `List<DTO>` with the results from the database, and you can start using them.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but the sql query is better expressed without nesting the second table, like this:

```
select  
    I.Dist, I.ID, D.ID, D.Temp,
    CAST(D.Hmd as float) Hmd,
    CAST(D.ActEvp as float) ActEvp 
from IFiles I 
inner join DFiles D ON cast(D.ID as int) = I.ID AND D.FileName = '1'
where I.FileName = 's1'
order by CAST(I.Dist as float)
```

Additionally, it looks like you're using string types for several columns that really should be stored as a number of some kind in the first place... at least the `DFiles.ID` and `IFiles.Dist` columns stand out. That's a **huge** problem with the schema. Stores those values as `int`/`float` in the first place.